# How can I debug a docker push on Mac using docker-machine?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

How can I get verbose debug on a "docker push" command that is failing?  I'm running docker-machine on a Mac with the VirtualBox driver.

I've seen the advice on setting the flags on the Docker daemom (Docker -d -D ) but as docker-machine is controlling the VirtualBox VM I'd guess it should be a docker-machine config.

I have scanned ~/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json but don't see an option for debugging and haven't found a reference for adding new options.  I gave the ArbitraryFlags option a try with no luck.